# Extrating timestamps from filename to split mp3s

Tags: regular-expression, zsh, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of mp3 files in a folder. They are recorded from cassette tape, and the individual tracks need to be separated out. This is one one the filenames:

```
Gobbolino the Witch's Cat, 10:52 The Hare & Tortoise, 14:52 The Shoe Tree, 24:22 The Emperors New Clothes, 34:11 The Red Nightcaps, 37:07 Aldo in Arcadia (1), 40:37 The Forest Troll.mp3
```

You can see it has timestamps within the filename, indicating the start of each track. The first track is not timestamped since it always starts at 00:00. And the last track should always go to the end of the mp3. Somehow, I want to extract these timestamps in order to create separate files.

If the file above were split correctly the output would be:

```
Gobbolino the Witch's Cat.mp3
The Hare & Tortoise.mp3
The Shoe Tree.mp3
The Emperors New Clothes.mp3
The Red Nightcaps.mp3
Aldo in Arcadia (1).mp3
The Forest Troll.mp3
```

I know how to loop thru files, and how to cut a file with ffmpeg, but I don't know how to extract the timestamps and track names from the filename. I'm using zsh, and here is my current code:

```
for file in *; do
  if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
    # extract timestamps and loop thru, for each timestamped section
    ffmpeg -ss TIMESTAMP_START -to TIMESTAMP_END -I "$file" -acodec copy TRACK_NAME.mp3
  fi
done
```

**UPDATE**

My spec for this problem has changed. The filename looks like this:

```
Tape 1 - Gobbolino the Witch's Cat, 11-06 The Hare & Tortoise, 14-25 The Shoe Tree, 24-06 The Emperors New Clothes, 34-27 The Red Nightcaps, 37-29 Aldo in Arcadia (1), 40-40 The Forest Troll.mp3
```

i.e it has an Album name at the beginning, and there are hyphens in the timestamps instead of colons (filenames can't have colons in macOS). Also, I wanted to insert some mp3 tags into the files, and put the tracks for each album in its own album folder.

I based my solution on Gilles one below. The script looks like this:

```
setopt interactive_comments
for file in *(.); do
    extension=$file:e
    rest=$file:r
    timestamp_start=0:00
    timestamp_duration=$(ffprobe -i "$file"  -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal -sexagesimal)
    timestamp_duration=${timestamp_duration%.*}
    tracknum=1
    while [[ $rest =~ ,\ *([0-9:]+-[0-9][0-9])\ * ]]; do
        track_name="$rest[1,$MBEGIN-1]"
        if [[ "$track_name" == *"Tape "* ]]; then
       albumname="${track_name%% - *}"
           track_name="${track_name#* - }"
           echo "\n\nALBUM NAME $albumname\n"
           mkdir $albumname
        fi
        rest=$rest[$MEND+1,-1]
        timestamp_end=$match[1]
        timestamp_end="${timestamp_end//-/:}"

    # echo "$timestamp_start $timestamp_end $track_name.$extension"
        ffmpeg -ss $timestamp_start -to $timestamp_end -i $file -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 256k -ar 44100 -metadata album="$albumname" -metadata title="$track_name" -metadata track="$tracknum" $track_name.$extension
        mv $track_name.$extension $albumname
        timestamp_start=$timestamp_end
        tracknum=$((tracknum+1))
        last_track_name="$rest:r"
    done
    if [[ -n $timestamp_end ]]; then
        # echo "$timestamp_start $timestamp_duration $last_track_name.$extension"
        ffmpeg -ss $timestamp_start -to $timestamp_duration -i $file -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 256k -ar 44100 -metadata album="$albumname" -metadata title="$last_track_name" -metadata track="$tracknum" $last_track_name.$extension
        mv $last_track_name.$extension $albumname
    fi
done
```

Comment: Pick a better text processing language, e.g. `perl`, where this is easy. Hint: compute the timestamp of end of `$file`, and set the list of output files to `"00:00 $file,$eof_timestamp EOF"`, to make it easier to parse.

Comment: @waltinator Nonsense. Zsh's text processing capabilities are a bit haphazard, but they're well up to this task. Even plain sh could cope with a bit more effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop over the file name to match track delimiters using regular expression matching with the `=~` [conditional expression operator](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions). The regular expression `,\ *([0-9:]+:[0-9][0-9])\ *` matches a comma followed by a timestamp with optional spaces around it.

`$file:e` and `$file:r` extract the file extension through [history modifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers).

Instead of looping over all files and then matching just the regular files, use a [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to match just regular files.

```
for file in *(.); do
    extension=$file:e
    rest=$file:r
    timestamp_start=0:00
    timestamp_end=
    while [[ $rest =~ ,\ *([0-9:]+:[0-9][0-9])\ * ]]; do
        track_name=$rest[1,$MBEGIN-1]
        rest=$rest[$MEND+1,-1]
        timestamp_end=$match[1]
        ffmpeg -ss $timestamp_start -to $timestamp_end -I $file -acodec copy $track_name.$extension
        timestamp_start=$timestamp_end
    done
    if [[ -n $timestamp_end ]]; then
        ffmpeg -ss $timestamp_end -I $file -acodec copy $rest.$extension
    else
        : # If you want special processing for single-track files, it goes here.
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I based my solution on this, and updated the question

Answer (score -1):

```
 awk -F "," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/,"",$i);gsub(/^[[:space:]]*/,"",$i);print $i".mp3"}}' file.txt
```

output

```
Gobbolino the Witch's Cat.mp3
The Hare & Tortoise.mp3
The Shoe Tree.mp3
The Emperors New Clothes.mp3
The Red Nightcaps.mp3
Aldo in Arcadia (1).mp3
The Forest Troll.mp3.mp3
```

Comment: Let me know the reason for down vote